# Unhandled Win32 Exception Error

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows

I'm running a win32 application developed using VB6 with some 3rd party controls. I get the following error: 'Unhandled win32 exception error occurred in myprogram.exe'. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Are you the author of that program or was is written by someone else you can't contact?

Comment: NB: I'am the author of the program.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off asking this at StackOverflow, which is dedicated to programming, but the short answer is you need to debug your program. You need to determine where the error occurs and then either fix it if it's in your code or look into other options relating to those controls.

Comment: John Gardeniers, Im on StackOverflow, I just thought there might be a setting I can change on Windows Server to enable the application to run.

Comment: No setting is going to remove the bug(s). This has to be properly debugged. Doing otherwise you stand an excellent chance of ending up with an unreliable server, because unhandled exceptions have a habit of corrupting other parts of the system.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to resolve this is to run drwtsn32 to get a crash dump, however if you see a message like that the app is likely handling its own exceptions and preventing the exception from propagating to Windows. You need to contact the author of the app. If you can modify the source code, remove the unhandled exception handler and build with debug symbols, let DrWatson catch the error for you, then open the crash dump in windbg to see where the exception was thrown in the first place. Fixing the error is left as an exercise.